# Как обрезать урл и откинуть название файла

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне обрезать название файла в конце ссылки, т.е. имеется подобная ссылка в переменной:

```
$url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/index.php';
```

название файла может быть любое, мне нужно получить все что идет до `index.php` для данного примера. Результат нужен - `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так?

```
$url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/index.php';

echo preg_replace("/[^\/]+$/", "", $url);
```